# Magento-Compare products Update immediately

Tags: php, magento

PHP-Magento, In Magento, when i add a product to compare it give the result 'The product -  has been added to comparison list'. This product will be added after few mins only. How can i get quick update in Magento-compare product items list. I get immediate update in here when I flush magento cashee from admin. Shall I get immediate update in compared-product-list?

Comment: You should be able to compare the items immediately, this almost sounds like a caching issue with your web browser...have you tried with a different browser?

Answer (score 1):

Add all products to the default category.